# remove app from notification

Tags: android

when i am test my app in `android device`, and close it, i can show it in notification area. can you tell me how can i remove from it by programatically?

Thanks
nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call cancel on your `NotificationManager`. The parameter of the cancel method is the ID of the notification that should be canceled. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29) is the API with the cancel method.

**UPDATE:**

For example:

```
// Creates a notification
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= 1234;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

// Removes the notification from the notification bar
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: can you give me one example ?

Answer (score 0):

// notification manager

```
_mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

// clear notification in login button click

```
_mNotificationManager.cancel(notication_ID);
```